# How to update sub-array?

Tags: express, feathersjs

I know how to create things in Feathers (`systemService.create(category);`), but how would I create something in a sub-collection?

I would like to insert `category` into `systemService[0].productCategories`, but haven’t figured out how to do that. Here's a screenshot of my service.

[image]

Does anyone have any tips on how I should proceed?

---

EDIT: Found a solution that *almost* works.

```
systemService.find((error, categories) => {
  const $id = categories[0]._id;

  systemService.update($id, {
    "$set": {
      "productCategories": [
        newCategory
      ]
    }
  });

  console.log(categories);
});
```

However, it just replaces what's already in `productCategories`, instead of adding to it. I've tried `patch`, but nothing happened (so I might've been doing it wrong, or it's not the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Mongoose or Mongodb the [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator should do what you need:

```
systemService.find((error, categories) => {
  const $id = categories[0]._id;

  systemService.update($id, {
    "$push": {
      "productCategories": [
        newCategory
      ]
    }
  });

  console.log(categories);
});
```